# Keep getting "undefined" when converting readStream to String in GridFS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http, gridfs

I'm working on a website that stores images in a MongoDB GridFS database and then can display one of the chosen images to the user.
The upload part is already working, but I'm having trouble with the download part of the image because whenever I try to convert the readStream from the database to a string, I get `undefined` in my console.

I think the problem lies around the readStream part, more specifically, the conversion from readStream to `String`. When I replaced the readStream with writeStream, I was able to get a perfect copy of my image downloaded.

However, I don't need that. What I need is for the image to be sent to the front-end.

I've tried a lot of different ideas like moving the createServer around and the `MongoClient.connect`. I've also tried different packages that supposedly convert a `stream` straight into a `String`.

```
MongoClient.connect(dbURL, function(err, client){
    if(err) throw err;

    // setting db name
    var db = client.db("formImgs");

    // bucket to interact with GridFS
    bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db);

    // loop to upload each image
    for(var i = 0; i < fileNames.length; i++){
        // uploads to the database using file locations
        fs.createReadStream("photos/" + fileNames[i]).pipe(bucket.openUploadStream(fileNames[i]))
        .on("error", function(e){
            // error handling
            console.log(e);
        }).on("finish", function(){
            // success
            console.log("Done uploading!");
        });
    }

    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream("photos/LaptopRegistry.png");
        bucket.openDownloadStreamByName("LaptopRegistry.png").pipe(readStream);


        var bufs = [];
        //  THIS IS WHERE I THINK MY CODE MESSES UP
        readStream.on("data", function(chunk){
            bufs.push(chunk);
        }).on("end", function(){
            var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
            base64 = fbuf.toString("base64");
        });

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        fs.readFile("index.html", function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.write(data);
            //insert use of base64 string here

        });
    });


    });
});
```